# How to get access to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have function that is called after full loading of page. This function create Google Map object:

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
}
```

Below this function there is method `click`:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
        // How to get instance map here?
    });
});
```

How I can get access to object `var map` in `$( ".click" )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add return statement to your function `initMap()` :

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    return map;
}

$(function() {
    var map = initMap();

    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
         // use map here
     });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can not initialize several time `initMap()`, because this function is called automatically when page loaded.

Comment: What you mean by _because this function is called automatically when page loaded._? from where?

Comment: When I call init again, it reloads map, this is problem

Comment: From where you call init the first time ?

Comment: From `<script src...>`

Comment: Please update your question with necessary information so we can help, _From <script src...>_ doesn't help we can't know what you mean (from callback or from another script file included or ..).

Answer (score 1):

You can put var outside the function:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
}

$(function() {
    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
        map // you can access map here :)

    });
});
```

If you need to check is map have been init, check is `map == undefined` or not.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex